# How to remove references to performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread in mysql 5.6?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, mysqldump

I have a Jira 6.4.7 instance running on MySQL 5.6.44. I'm in the progress of updating the Jira instance to 7.0.5, which still supports MySQL 5.6.

I accidentally hooked up a newer Jira 7.0.5 to the same database, wich inserted `performance_schema` tables. Jira 7.0.5 probably thought it was running with >= mysql 5.7.

I immediately stopped the Jira 7.0.5 instance, but the references to `performance_schema` are still there.

When I look at the database with MySQL Workbench, I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1146 Table 'performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread' doesn't exist
```

Everything still seems to work with jira 6.4.7, but I can't dump the database anymore to move it somewhere else.

I've tried using the xml export and import from jira, but this copies the error from the database.

I've tried

```
[mysqld]
performance_schema=OFF
```

but the error persists.

I couldn't find the `performance_schema` table in other MySQL databases, because then I could have copied the table.

So how can I fix this? Can anyone provide an SQL statement of how this table should look like? Or how can I find and delete the references to `performance_schema` in my current MySQL 5.6 database?.

Comment: what workbench version? It could be that workbench is looking for the perf schema table, not JIRA. ref [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56298805/mysql-workbench-error-when-connecting-to-mariadb-table-performance-schema-user)

Comment: 8.0.16 - you were right, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was using MySQLWorkbench 8.0.16 and mysqldump 8.0.19 which are both looking for `performance_schema` tables in MySQL 5.6, which only exist starting with MySQL 5.7. Updating MySQLWorkbench to 8.0.20 and using mysqldump with the flag `--column-statistics=0` made the errors go away.

Answer (score 2):

`performance_schema.user_variables_by_thread` is in MySQL-5.7 but not MySQL-5.6. It cannot be copied as its generated by the server to represent the internal state.

MySQL-5.6 seems to have deprecated Jira support per https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/supported-platforms-938846830.html

[MySQL-5.7 reference on user_variables_by_thread](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-user-variable-tables.html)

Comment: Oh ok not in mysql 5.6. I've updated my question.